# In heroku python tutorial, virtualenv issues installing wsgiref (ez_setup syntax error?)

Tags: python, heroku, virtualenv, wsgi

I'm going through the Heroku tutorial "Getting Started with Python." I'm at the step where I want to build my environment locally with virtualenv so I can run the test app locally. The requirements.txt includes

```
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

and upon getting to that step virutalenv outputs the following error message

```
Downloading/unpacking wsgiref==0.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading wsgiref-0.1.2.zip
  Running setup.py egg_info for package wsgiref
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/v6/zf84tlbn19zcqlbx977nlrmh0000gn/T/pip_build_jeremy/wsgiref/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import ez_setup
      File "./ez_setup/__init__.py", line 170
        print "Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed."
                                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/v6/zf84tlbn19zcqlbx977nlrmh0000gn/T/pip_build_jeremy/wsgiref/setup.py", line 5, in <module>

    import ez_setup

  File "./ez_setup/__init__.py", line 170

    print "Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed."

                             ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's clear to me *what's* happening: at some point python3.3 (my default) is being used to install something through a python2.x script. I just don't know how to fix it. My virtualenv only has Python3.x utilities, and I'm not sure what ez_setup is, even after reading its worrisome-looking [PyPI entry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ez_setup).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you only have Python 3.3 installed? You don't need `wsgiref` for Python 3.3 and can safely remove this from the requirements file.

Comment: Maybe being captain obvious here, but have you `source bin/activate`?

Comment: @ham-sandwich yes that was part of the tutorial. (Also I don't know what it does, maybe you could explain?)

Comment: @JeremyKun sure, I'll submit an answer, I just need to replicate the issue first. Obviously Heroku doesn't support the 3.x series yet, so I think that the problem is when you start the virtualenv. Can you try and write in your terminal `python2 virtualenv myproject` and see if it is successful.

Comment: Assuming you have also Python 2 installed in your system, you can create a virtualenv with a specific version `virtualenv -p <path_to_your_python> <env_name>`

Comment: It looks like Heroku does support Python 3.x, cf https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes

Comment: I don't think the solution I'm looking for is to downgrade to Python2.x. Actually, the comment of @BurhanKhalid is more helpful: wsgiref comes packaged with Python3.3, and I just need to change the runtime.txt to tell Heroku to use Python3.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heroku supports Python versions [2.4.4 through 3.4.1](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/tree/master/builds/runtimes).

The tutorial you are using is designed for Python 2.7.8, which is why your application is not working locally. If you were to push the application up to Heroku, it would work properly.

You have two options here, you can either install Python 2.7 on your local machine, or you can modify the tutorial to work with Python 3.x

For the first option, using your package manager or other normal tool, install Python 2.x. If you are using redhat or other rpm-based distribution (like centos, fedora, etc.) be careful not to overwrite the system Python, as rpm tools like `yum` will stop working.

Once you have installed Python 2.7.x, you'll have to install pip and setuptools against that version of Python. Finally, create your virtual environment and then continue with the tutorial.

If you want to stick with Python 3.3, then you'll have to make the following adjustments from the repository you have cloned:

1. In `runtime.txt`, change `python-2.7.8` to `python-3.3`
2. Change your `requirements.txt` to the following:

   ```
   django-toolbelt
   ```

You don't need anything else, `django-toolbelt` is just a meta package which will install django, gunicorn, psycopg2, dj-database-url and dj-static.

Create a new virtual environment and then install these requirements.

Comment: I have the similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852789/heroku-cannot-change-the-python-runtime-version-to-3-4-2